# Pyrogram oserror tcptransport handler is close

Tags: python

I use pyrogram and handler, and when I increase the number of groups, I get this error when running on the host, what's the problem?

```
raise e from None
File "/home/tabssit2/virtualenv/2baT/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrog
ram/session/session.py", line 389, in invoke
return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/tabssit2/virtualenv/2baT/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrog ram/session/session.py", line 340, in send
raise e
File "/home/tabssit2/virtualenv/2baT/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrog ram/session/session.py", line 337, in send
await self.connection.send(payload)
File "/home/tabssit2/virtualenv/2baT/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrog ram/connection/connection.py", line 69, in send
await self.protocol.send(data)
File "/home/tabssit2/virtualenv/2baT/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrog ram/connection/transport/tcp/tcp_abridged.py", line 38, in send
await super().send(
File "/home/tabssit2/virtualenv/2baT/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrog ram/connection/transport/tcp/tcp.py", line 104, in send
raise OSError(e)
OSError: unable to perform operation on <TCPTransport closed=True reading-Fa 1se 0x55e969ef2de0>; the handler is closed
[10] Retrying "updates.GetState" due to: unable to perform operation on <TCP Transport closed-True reading False Ox55e969ef2de0>; the handler is closed
```

I use asyncio and uvloop and await and tgcrypto
My problem was not solved

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know which part the error is related to, I used the handle @bot.on_message()

Comment: It seems like you are calling `send` on a closed session. But it's hard to tell without any code.